# SOAP UI does not return expected output when published

Tags: c#, soap, soapui, asmx

I have this SOAP request that works as expected while debugging. It returned 36 XML nodes.
[image: Success response with expected output]

I wonder why its response is different when I published it to my local IIS. My expected output must be 36 XML nodes also.

[image: Success response with out expected output]

I use c# asmx and mssql server.

Here's my code returning 36 rows from sql server.
[image: C# code returning 36 rows]

Comment: how About your Code?

Comment: It appears to be server sided but one would need more information and code in order to tell.

Comment: I am using the same PC while debugging and after publish. Please view my post. I edited it and added another screenshot

Comment: Please post the script as text instead of screen shot. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I am able to solve it by setting ADODB's Embed Interop Types property from true to false.

References > ADODB > Properties Window > Embed Interop Types > False